# Viewer Node doesn't show up

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

So I am watching a tutorial and I am supposed to create a viewer node to connect it with a fresnel. I searched through the internet and everyone is saying that I only have to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd>  but no matter how often I try to press those buttons, nothing happens.

It should pop up, right? I don't know what to do anymore. Cause apparently this is important for the next steps I have to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the *Node Wrangler* addon.

Just enable it in preferences, and you're done.
*Preferences->Addons* and click the checkmark.

Remember to Save Preferences.
Restart Blender.
Done.

[image]

Comment: OMG youre a genius. Thank you so much . You saved my evening. I was raging so hard :D

Comment: @Siddy No problem, we've all been there. Please mark the answer as accepted now (the green checkmark), for other lost souls that'll come here in the future :).