# Nodes connecting

Tags: node-editor

Trying to understand how people connect a *Fresnel* node into *Viewer* node.

I saw the *Viewer* node apear after *Fresnel* , so looking for some clarification.

Comment: My guess on your "question": Enable Node Wrangler, Ctrl+Shift click the node. Please add more information to help us understand what you want.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to give more details. Also check [ask] and take the [tour] to learn how the site works.

Comment: As @brockmann suggested, use [node wrangler](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/node/node_wrangler.html#node-wrangler) add-on. Viewer node is really nothing more than an emission shader with a label that says "viewer" anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Viewer Node doesn't show up](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159171/viewer-node-doesnt-show-up)